# Unable to Insert Into Database asp.net Using C# - Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to insert user data into a database using an asp.net form created in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I am getting the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to find control id
>   'txtName' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'reqName'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to find control id 'txtName'
>   referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'reqName'.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String
>   name, String propertyName) +183
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +36
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +166
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +236
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4713

c# code to insert user data into database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table values('" + pName.Text + "','" + pEmail.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

My database file has two rows, one for the name (pName) and the other for the e-mail (pEmail)

Comment: Do you have any control defined as txtName?

Comment: The error does not have anything to do with your insert.

Comment: I could not find anything defined as txtName...except pName.Text would be the closest I would get to that. Any thoughts on what is causing the issue??

Answer (score 1):

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to find control id 'txtName'
>   referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'reqName'.]

The message is clear, on your aspx page (not on code behind) you have define for validation a control (`txtName`) that is not exist on page!, on the `reqName` control, on the `ControlToValidate` parameter....

Comment: I updated the code to resolve ControlToValidate, now there is stack empty error. Any thoughts on how I can tweak the current to successfully insert data into form?

Comment: @penmas Please make new question. Because you actually change totally the question...